# How can I make dynamic JQueryUI elements sortable and resizable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-resizable

In my JQueryUI test of resizable and sortable elements when I attempt to add objects dynamically, it loses its ability to be resized. It works well when it is statically included in the HTML DOM.

HTML

```
<button id="content">click</button>
<div class="row-fluid" id="sortable"></div>
```

CSS

```
.sort_container {
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  cursor: grab;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
}

#segrip {
  width: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #888;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: -5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

JS

```
  var customElement =
  "" +
  '<div class="span6 sort_container">' +
  '    <div class="well">1</div>' +
  '    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip"></div>' +
  "</div>" +
  "";

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable();
  });

  $(".sort_container").resizable({
    handles: {
      se: ".ui-resizable-se"
    }
  });
  $("#content").on("click", function (e) {
    $(customElement).appendTo($("#sortable"));
  });
});
```

**Code**
https://codepen.io/sandeepzgk1/pen/zYjqWZP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeCard() {
    var index = $(".sort_container").length + 1;
    var el = $("<div>", {
      class: "span6 sort_container"
    });
    $("<div>", {
      class: "well"
    }).html(index).appendTo(el);
    $("<div>", {
      id: "segrip-" + index,
      class: "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"
    }).appendTo(el);
    return el;
  }

  $("#sortable").sortable();

  $("#content").on("click", function(e) {
    var customElement = makeCard();
    customElement.appendTo("#sortable");
    customElement.resizable({
      handles: {
        se: ".ui-resizable-se"
      }
    });
    $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
  });
});
```

```css
.sort_container {
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  cursor: grab;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
}

[id^=segrip-] {
  width: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #888;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: -5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="content">Click</button>
<div class="row-fluid" id="sortable"></div>
```

Resizable is not working and I am still looking at that. When you add dynamic items to sortable, you must `refrsh` the list. Also you cannot assign resizble to an element that does not yet exist. This is why it was not working for you.

Comment: just a followup on best practices on how to add HTML within JS, is there a better way than subdividing it into multiple likes, say importing it from a file so that the component can be developed independently and not as crazy inbetween js stuff?

Comment: I believe the best practice is to add them as DOM objects. It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish in your comment. It's also going to depend on a number of variables. You might just load it using `.load()` option or importing it as JSON or XML. You might want to post a new question with amore complete example.